# prove with $GAP$ in group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, gap

My problem: with $GAP$ prove there exists a group $G$, $|G|=32$ and maximal subgroup $M$ such that $\text{Aut}(G) \cong \text{Aut}(M)$.

It is clear that $G$ is $p$-group, ($32=2^5$), but with $GAP$ we have:

> There are $51$ groups of order $32$.
>
> They are sorted by their ranks.
>
> $1$ is cyclic.
>
> $2\ldots20$ have rank $2$.
>
> $21\ldots44$ have rank $3$.
>
> $45\ldots50$ have rank $4$.
>
> $51$ is elementary Abelian.

[Here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_32) is list of all Groups of order $32$, but there are $51$ groups of order $32$. My question: which of [this group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_32) is exactly the answer? How can we find it? How can we find "IdSmallGroup($32$)" with the above property? What is StructureDescription of $G$ and $M$?

I think there is exactly one group. Is this group with this property unique? What is the GAP ID of this group?

Comment: There is a Software Carpentry-style introductory lesson on programming in GAP here: https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/. It is centred around a problem of searching for a group with specific properties in the GAP Small Groups Library - hope it will be of some help here.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you describe the process you would the computer like to do in steps?

Comment: @ahulpke  I find answer is : $(C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2) : C_4$ with $M \leq G$ maximal, isomorphic to $C_2 \times D_8$ but i can't find GAP ID of this group and GAP ID of  $C_2 \times D_8$ ?

Comment: also i find , GAP ID of  $C_2 \times D_8$ is "11" (Second part of GAP ID)

Comment: now i find , Faithful semidirect product of $E8$ and $Z_4$ GAP ID (2nd part) is "6" ( GAP ID $G$).